# generating self signed SSL Certificate for apache on window vista

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-vista, ssl-certificate

I do not have any idea about generating self signed SSL Certificate for apache on window vista, but I have to do that. So, can anybody help me? I want some link or some proper guide which can help me for generating self signed SSL Certificate for apache on window vista and how I can configure this generated self signed SSL Certificate in virtual hosts.

please reply me as soon as possible.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may give [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) a try. Install it on your Vista machine, add the openssl package during the setup. To generate your CSR: [Cygwin with OpenSSL for CSR generation](http://www.booches.nl/2008/09/18/cygwin-with-openssl-for-csr-generation/). Then issue the CSR at [CACert.org](http://www.cacert.org/) to get your SSL certificate (you need to create an account there, but it is worth it imho).
In opposite to the traditional self-signed certificate, you'll get a SSL certificate that's signed by a public authority for free.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [openssl windows binary](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) to generate/sign certificates.